# Doctrine BETWEEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to fetch data using doctrine by BETWEEN

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("E")
    ->select("E.id,E.publicationStatus,E.isArchived,E.isCancelled")
    ->where("E.publicationPlannedFromDate BETWEEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE `AND` CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()");

return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

But his gives me error

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 250: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_AND, got '5'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom [DQL custom user defined functions](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html) or just query builder expression methods. For the second one, you can change your query as following:

```
$qb->select("E.id, E.publicationStatus, E.isArchived, E.isCancelled")
    ->from('Entity', 'E')
    ->add("WHERE",
        $qb->expr()->between(
            "E.publicationPlannedFromDate",
            "DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 5, 'MINUTE')",
            "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()"
        )
    );
```